# Quickly retrieve unique integers from PySpark DataFrame array of lists of integers?

Tags: pyspark

Suppose you had a Pyspark DataFrame, `df`:

```
DataFrame[set_sid_index: array<int>]
```

That looks like:

```
+--------------------+
|       set_sid_index|
+--------------------+
|           [8, 0, 1]|
|              [8, 1]|
|                 [9]|
|                 [0]|
|                 [2]|
|           [0, 1, 3]|
|           [8, 0, 1]|
|[22, 2, 6, 0, 1, 21]|
|  [2, 0, 1, 4, 5, 3]|
|              [0, 1]|
|           [0, 1, 3]|
|              [0, 1]|
|                 [9]|
|      [2, 105, 4, 3]|
+--------------------+
```

and another PySpark DataFrame, `df2`:

```
DataFrame[set_sid_index: array<int>]

+--------------------+
|       set_sid_index|
+--------------------+
|           [8, 0, 1]|
+--------------------+
```

How would you convert the elements of the lists in `df`'s array such that any element that is not `{0, 1, 8}` (the unique elements of `df2`), is converted to a "0", or a "1", or an "8"?

--- Clarification of above paragraph ---

For my particular use case , I'd have to find `uniq`, which would be the set of unique elements from an array of lists of integers. So to be specific, in the example I gave above, `df2` only had one list with unique values (0, 1, 8). In reality, `df2` will have multiple lists with overlapping values. I'd need `uniq` = `unique(df2values)`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit puzzled by your "convert to either 0, or 1, or 8"; so, let's be more precise:

> if element of 1-st df is not in in the array [0, 1, 8], we convert it to `0`

Given this qualification, let's start.

We have:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
uniq = [8, 0, 1]
sdf.show()
+--------------------+
|       set_sid_index|
+--------------------+
|           [8, 0, 1]|
|              [8, 1]|
|                 [9]|
|                 [0]|
|                 [2]|
|           [0, 1, 3]|
|           [8, 0, 1]|
|[22, 2, 6, 0, 1, 21]|
|  [2, 0, 1, 4, 5, 3]|
|              [0, 1]|
|           [0, 1, 3]|
|              [0, 1]|
|                 [9]|
|      [2, 105, 4, 3]|
+--------------------+


sdf.printSchema()
root
 |-- set_sid_index: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

Now let's define a simple `udf` and apply it:

```
convertToZero = udf(lambda x: [0 if i not in uniq else i for i in x], ArrayType(IntegerType()))
sdf.withColumn('set_sid_index', convertToZero(sdf['set_sid_index'])).show(truncate=False)
+------------------+
|set_sid_index     |
+------------------+
|[8, 0, 1]         |
|[8, 1]            |
|[0]               |
|[0]               |
|[0]               |
|[0, 1, 0]         |
|[8, 0, 1]         |
|[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]|
|[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 1]            |
|[0, 1, 0]         |
|[0, 1]            |
|[0]               |
|[0, 0, 0, 0]      |
+------------------+
```

**UPDATE**

Suppose you do not have a readily available `uniq` array.

Then:

```
sdf2.show()
+--------------------+
|       set_sid_index|
+--------------------+
|[22, 2, 6, 0, 1, 21]|
|  [2, 0, 1, 4, 5, 3]|
|              [0, 1]|
+--------------------+

x = sdf2.withColumn('set_sid_index', explode(sdf2['set_sid_index'])).drop_duplicates().collect()
uniq = [i[0] for i in x]
uniq
[0, 22, 6, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 21]
```

Comment: Yes, this is a very good answer. For my particular use case though, I'd have to find `uniq`, which would be the set of unique elements from an array of lists of integers. So to be specific, in the example I gave above, df2 only had one list with unique values (0, 1, 8). In reality, df2 will have multiple lists with overlapping values. I'd need `uniq` = `unique(df2values)`. How do I do that?

Comment: @user2205916 Does this answer your question as stated? If so, I'd suggest upvote and accept it. If you have some other questions, why not open another question and I will gladly provide you with a solution?

Comment: Sure. I clarified the question above. I'm not sure a separate question makes sense, since it's really a very minor extension of the above. Thanks!

Comment: The above code generates an ImportError: Cannot import numpy.core.multiarray. I believe the error message is due to the lack of a numpy install on my cluster's worker nodes (?) and the ArrayType() function call in the solution. Is there a non-numpy data structure that can be used instead of ArrayType that achieves the same results?